# I want that when I press Enter Button then ok button work

Tags: c#

How do set a button default for enter key?

I want that when I press enter a particular button will be triggered.

Comment: where do you want that ?

Comment: In Winforms, in a web page, somewhere else ?

Comment: If you are talking about windows forms, set `AcceptButton`

Answer (score 1):

Use `AcceptButton` property in a Form to use selected button for accept

Answer (score 0):

The form object has an AcceptButton property. Just set it to your desired button

Answer (score 0):

you can put defaultbutton property in form tag

```
<form runat="server"  defaultbutton="Button1">
```